# View extent not set correctly when displaying GeoTiff

Tags: cartopy

Cartopy=0.22, PyProj=3.6.1, Matplotlib=3.8.2, python=3.9

I have a Geotiff with a CRS of EPSG:2289.  The file can be downloaded from [here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/EwFkMsfhF4gLoVKD7)

When I attempt to read and display this image using the code below, the limits of the window are not set to the image extent. As a consequence the image is not displayed.

The code I have been using to display the Geotiff is as follows:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import rasterio
import numpy as np

fname = r'image.tif'

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 12))

with rasterio.Env():
    with rasterio.open(fname, 'r') as src:

        #Get the epsg code from the source file
        code = src.crs.to_epsg()
       
        try:
            projection = ccrs.epsg(code)
        except:
            raise ValueError("Error converting EPSG code")

        img = src.read()
        img = np.transpose(img, [1,2,0])

        ax = plt.axes(projection=projection)

        # Fetch extent of raster in projection units
        xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = src.bounds
        img_extent = [xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax]
        
        # Add the image.     
        ax.imshow(img, origin='upper', extent=img_extent, transform=projection)

        print("Showing extent",img_extent)
        print("Axes extent",ax.get_extent())
        print("View limits are", ax.dataLim)

        plt.show()
```

This code executes without error and displays a window but with no image in it.

The same image displays in the correct location in GIS (QGIS).

With other images I have tested using the same code, the view limits are automatically set to the image extent and the image displays correctly.

I am wondering whether this may be an issue with the Lambert Conformal Projection of this image as my other images are Transverse Mercator, but this is speculation.

Any guidance or insight appreciated.

Comment: I found some additional images in Lambert Conformal and those also open and display correctly, so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: I now suspect that the root cause is that, while the Geotiff has been coded with State Plane Wisconsin South, the actual location was in Illinois East, about 20 miles outside of the bounds of the WI coordinate system.  I am not sure why Cartopy doesn't adjust the view limits in this case.  Still investigating.

Comment: Filed as an issue and potential bug at https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/2320